# NullPointerException why?

Tags: android, listview, view, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I need some help. Below should be all u need.

LogCat(updated) /

```
    04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at pl.smarterp2.ZamowienieAdd$sec_Fragment_zp.Clicker(ZamowienieAdd.java:1450)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at pl.smarterp2.ZamowienieAdd$sec_Fragment_zp.onCreateView(ZamowienieAdd.java:1465)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-17 11:31:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code(updated) /

```
public static class sec_Fragment_zp extends Fragment{

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public sec_Fragment_zp() { }

        //ListView lv = setContentView();
        public void Clicker()
        {
            View lView = this.getView();
            final ListView lista_zam = (ListView) lView.findViewById(R.id.zamadd_lista); 

            lista_zam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    lista_zam.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zaplacono);
                }
            });
        }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zamowienie_fragment2, container, false);     
                Clicker();
                return myLayout;    
            }
```

I can't realize why it doesnt work.

Simply i just want to change background after click on List item. It's not my project im making some changes only. If u want more code ask(i have bunch). I have no idea why it doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NullPointer is here

```
final View lView = this.getView();
```

because `Clicker(container);` will call first before creating view.So Change

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Clicker(container);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zamowienie_fragment2, container, false);          
    }
```

to

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_zamowienie_fragment2, container, false);     
        Clicker(container);
        return myLayout;    
    }
```

Comment: changed

lista_zam = (ListView)lView.findViewById(R.id.zamadd_lista); 

NullPointer here.

Btw. it makes any difference if it is OnItemClickListener or OnClickListener?

Comment: then lView should be final?

Comment: I changed lista_zam = (ListView)lView.findViewById(R.id.zamadd_lista);  to lista_zam = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.zamadd_lista); ...... I moved to next line: lista_zam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
now here is NullPointer.

Comment: Check your log and make sure that same log generated or different?BTW which line you got null pointer?

Comment: @Filip Remove parameter from `Clicker` method and and do change as I suggested then it should work.

Comment: Its sill not working.  NullPointerException here:    final ListView lista_zam = (ListView) lView.findViewById(R.id.zamadd_lista);

Comment: @Filip Check id of listview in `activity_zamowienie_fragment2` file.

Comment: Here it is.. :) if u rly want i can put all code, but its almost 2000 lines ;P